# Upload File to Skydrive on Android

Tags: android, onedrive

I am writing an Android app which needs to occasionally upload a file to SkyDrive. I know that you can do this through the share dialog, but I would like to do it automatically within my app. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Do I need to invoke an Intent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload files to SkyDrive using Microsoft's SkyDrive API. The API is hosted on github: https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-Android

Here you can find Android Code Samples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh875196.aspx